# How to use foreach with lambda for Map<Integer,Map<String,String>>

Tags: java, lambda, foreach

How can i use forEach with lamba for something like:

```
Map<Integer,Map<String,String>
```

i want to check if Map (this - string,string) contains key in function parameter

thanks for help ;)

Comment: @rmlan I think OP wants to search the nested maps.

Comment: I just realized that. However, I still think this is a pretty low-quality question as it does not demonstrate much effort on OP's part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static boolean containsInnerKey(String key, Map<Integer, Map<String, String>> map) {
    return map.values()
            .stream()
            .anyMatch(m -> m.containsKey(key));
}
```